# Ни кола ни двора

Tags: фразеология

Есть такая поговорка "ни кола ни двора" (кстати, нужна ли тут запятая?). Так говорят о том, у кого ничего нет, малоимущем, нищем или бездомном.
Я понимаю насчет "не двора" - то есть, у человека нет дома и, соответственно, двора. Но при чем тут кол? Могу со своей стороны предположить, что речь идет о частоколе - заборе, состоящем из заостренных кольев. Но почему тогда речь об одном коле, а не о заборе в целом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Интернете нашёл такое объяснение:

> > В старину в некоторых местностях колом называлась **полоса пахотной земли шириной в две сажени (около 4,5 метра)**.
> > Не иметь кола значило «не иметь и маленького клочка земли». Выражение ни кола ни двора означает наивысшую степень бедности.

Если вспомнить такие производные слова, как "околица", "около", то можно предположить, что и сам "кол" мог иметь значение некоторого пространства.

Стоит отметить, что в толковых словарях подтверждения этому я не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

В старину в некоторых местностях колом называлась полоса пахотной земли шириной в две сажени (около 4,5 метра).
Не иметь кола значило «не иметь и маленького клочка земли». Выражение *ни кола ни двора* означает наивысшую степень бедности.

Comment: Что-то я не слышал такого значения. Да и по семантики не подходит. Коло - круг. Кол - сами знаете что. При чем тут полоса в две сажени? Источник назовете?